# Pascal: variable i : 1..10;

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have this part of code. My question is what the variable  `i: 1..10;` is and what am I declaring. Thanks

```
type
Str25 = String[25];
TBookRec = Record
  Title, Author, ISBN : Str25;
  Price : Real;
End;

Var
BookRecArray : Array[1..10] of TBookRec;
tempBookRec : TBookRec;
bookRecFile : File of TBookRec;
i : 1..10;
```

Comment: `i` is an integer between 1 and 10 (including the end points). Hence, `i` is a variable that can have one of the following values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10. See [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Subrange_Types).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the variable I is declared like this:

```
var i : 1..10;
```

it means that variable i is an integer subrange which can take a value between 1 and 10 inclusive.

The code you show is frequently declared like this:

```
type
    Str25 = String[25];
    TBookRec = Record
        Title, Author, ISBN : Str25;
        Price : Real;
    End;

    TBookRecIndex = 1..10;

var
   BookRecArray : Array [TBookRecIndex] of TBookRec;
   TempBookRec  : TBookRec;
   BookRecFile  : File of TBookRec;
   I            : TBookRecIndex;
```

Comment: There's no *rule* that says an answer must be accepted, and no requirement for the OP to do so.